# C# - Changing Input Language Keyboard Layout (Ex: Set Greek (319) under Greek Language)

Tags: c#, layout, keyboard

Note: Input Languages and keyboard layouts are not the same thing. One Input Language can have multiple layouts (ex: US English and Dvorak, Dvorak Left, and Dvorak Right).

I'm writing a program that will be used to test almost every keyboard layout in Windows 7. I've successfully been able to change the Input Language in my program, but if the Input Language has multiple layouts I can only change to the default one. This is a problem for US English (multiple Dvorak layouts), Greek (includes Greek 220, Greek 319, Greek Polytonic, etc).

The code I am currently using to change Input Languages is:

```
string cultureChange = "{en-US}"; //just an example
InputLanguage nextLang = InputLanguage.FromCulture(cultureChange);
ChangeInputLanguage(nextLang);

public void ChangeInputLanguage(InputLanguage InputLang)
{
    // Check is this Language really installed. Raise exception to warn if it is not:
    if (InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.IndexOf(InputLang) == -1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    // InputLanguage changes here:
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLang;
}
```

Input Languages have Culture, LayoutName, and Handle properties. The problem is that between layouts of the same Input Language (ex Dvorak and default US English) both have exactly the same Culture info (LCID and KeyboardLayoutID is 1033 for both), but different LayoutNames and Handles. But the only way to change the application's language is using Culture, as far as I can tell.

Comment: One of the few cases where the Handle property has a meaningful value. Convert it to hex and you'll see the pattern, the low and high word both contain the LCID for the default layout.  So 0x04090409 for US.

Answer (score 0):

I googled my way to some code that works, posting the answer in case anyone needs this info. **I have no idea what this code means but it seems to work.**

```
public partial class myForm : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern long GetKeyboardLayoutName(
          System.Text.StringBuilder pwszKLID);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hhwnd, uint msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadKeyboardLayout(string pwszKLID, uint Flags);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    private const uint WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST = 0x0050;
    private const uint KLF_ACTIVATE = 1;
//etc more form code
```

and then in a button press event:

```
//Gets current keyboard layout
StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder(9);
GetKeyboardLayoutName(name);
String KeyBoardLayout = name.ToString();
//Changes current layout to Dvorak (which is 00010409)
PostMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, IntPtr.Zero, LoadKeyboardLayout("00010409", KLF_ACTIVATE));
```

I plan on hard-coding the layout changes that I need, which is not the most elegant solution but the languages under test for my application will probably not change, so I'm fine with this as a solution.